# Precompile assets on Heroku

Tags: php, node.js, heroku, express

Everywhere online talks about Rails when it comes to building assets during slug compilation.  Is there a way to do this with the other languages like Node.js or PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I have a situation where I need to compile my javascript files with Closure-Compiler and I created a script that calls the compiler and when it's done, it's call `node app.js`. Then in your `Procfile`, you need to call you newly created script. Something like `web: ./compile_and_start_server.sh`

You can also check for the "prestart" in package.json but this I never tried it.

https://npmjs.org/doc/scripts.html